# Java "Not a statement" error (Net Beans)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, netbeans, user-input

I need to be able to have the user input the starting number, the ending number, and the increment. I probably did this horribly wrong but it's late and I'm completely lost. It's telling me that my for-loop is "not a statement."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ForDemo{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Input a starting number: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int start, end, inc;
        start = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input an ending number: ");
        end = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input an increment: ");
        inc = keyboard.nextInt();

        for(int count = start; count <= end; count + (inc)){
            System.out.print(count + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: last statement in your for loop should be `count += inc`

Comment: I think you should intend your code correctly, it makes it much easier for yourself (and others) to read / comprehend it, i fixed it and removed the unnecessary block inside the main

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
 for(int count = start; count <= end; count += inc){
    System.out.print(count + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the increment to count in your `for` loop

Try

```
for(int count = start; count <= end; count = count + (inc))
```

instead of

```
for(int count = start; count <= end; count + (inc))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues :

1. Change your for loop to :

   for(int count = start; count <= end; count+= (inc)){
       System.out.print(count + " ");
   }
2. You don't need a *code block* here

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       {// not needed
       System.out.println("Input a starting number: ");
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       int start, end, inc;
       start = keyboard.nextInt();

   ```
   System.out.println("Input an ending number: ");
   end = keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Input an increment: ");
   inc = keyboard.nextInt();




   for(int count = start; count <= end; count+= (inc)){
       System.out.print(count + " ");
   }
   } // not needed
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

use parenthesis in for loop as follows

```
for(int count = start; count <= end; (count += inc)){
    System.out.print(count + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The increment component of the for statement is supposed to be either a valid statement or empty. `count+(inc)` is **Not a** valid **statement**. `count=count+(inc)` would be a valid statement.

The JavaSE tutorial explains the for statement well:
**[The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)**

This question has little to do with Netbeans.